# How to create google geo chart like map in iphone?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, charts

I want to display map like geo chart api in google [Geo chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html#Methods)

and highlight particular country. How to Achieve This in offline..

Any Suggestions please..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at something like the data from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) and put it in a either a sqlite3 or spatialite database. Then create a georeferenced view that will translate points on the screen to lat/lon coordinates and vice versa. Finally you can look up the lat/lon coordinates in the database to draw the country outlines and highlight the countries while you draw the screen.

If you are thinking of zooming the map, you probably want to look at getting multiple resolutions for the data as drawing a high resolution map can be slow.